# Will repeatedly passing a table to a function allocate more memory?

Tags: unit-testing, garbage-collection, lua, pass-by-reference

i have a function in Lua that operates on a table, repeatedly adding entries to the table:

```
function DoStuff()
    local table = {};

    for i = 1, 1000 do
        local name, value = GetSomething(i);

        if (CheckSomething(name, value))
           table[name] = value
        end;
    end;
end;
```

i know this is fast; Lua has a good hash table algorithm. But now i need to split out part of my function, so i may unit test it:

```
function DoStuff()
    local table = {};

    for i = 1, 1000 do
        local name, value = GetSomething(i);

        --split out checking so it's testable
        table = ParseTheThing(table, name, value); 
    end;
end;
```

i know that [Lua does not support passing paramters by **reference**](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2004-06/msg00257.html), instead if i need to add an item to my **`table`**, Lua will make a copy and i must return that copy:

```
--Core checking function
function ParseTheThing(table, name, value)
   if (CheckSomething(name, value))
      table[name] = value
   end;

   return table;
end;
```

So it seems to me that every time i call **`CheckSomething`** Lua will create *another* table, that needs to be garbage collected.

Or maybe not. Maybe Lua **does** support passing parameters by reference, and i can simply call:

```
ParseTheThing(table, name, value); 

--Core checking function
function ParseTheThing(table, name, value)
   if (CheckSomething(name, value))
      table[name] = value
   end;
end;
```

---

Will Lua's garbage collector be forced into doing a lot more work if i refactor my code as i have done?

---

**Notes**:

- Don't confuse the simplified example used in the question with the question i'm asking.
- i don't have any way to measure memory usage, or number of collections, so i cannot *try it*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know that Lua does not support passing paramters by reference

The term "by reference" is overloaded, causing a lot of confusion (especially in the [Java world](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html) where I've seen people refuse to acknowledge that one of the meanings even exists).

Passing by reference can mean:

1. Passing the *location* of an object in memory, rather than the object itself. This is what is meant by ["pass by reference" in C](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr233.htm). In this sense, Java *does* pass by reference, and so does Lua for many of its types (userdata, tables, etc.).
2. An alias for a variable, such that any modifications to the alias is reflected in the original. This goes beyond simply not passing by value; if the variable holds a location of an object, you can assign a different location through the alias. You can't do this for #1, where you pass a reference to an *object*, not a variable. These types of references are supported in C#, C++, etc., but not C or Lua.

More simply:

1. Pass by value: The object in the calling function is a copy of the object received by the called function.
2. Pass by reference^1: The object in the calling function can be modified by the called function.
3. Pass by reference^2: The variable in the calling function can be modified by the called function.

> instead if i need to add an item to my table

Just pass the table -- a reference, not a copy, is passed.

Comment: Technically, C++ doesn't have "alias for a variable" references either. A reference variable is a variable which stores a reference to an object. It's no different than passing a table around in Lua.

Comment: From the Lua manual: "Tables, functions, threads, and (full) userdata values are objects: variables do not actually contain these values, only references to them. Assignment, parameter passing, and function returns always manipulate references to such values; these operations do not imply any kind of copy."